# Спавн игроков в юнити в разных скинах

Tags: c#, unity3d

Уже неделю бьюсь на тем как сделать, чтобы игроки спавнились в разных скинах в онлайн игре(то есть из list удалялся скин который не надо спавнить).
Вот что уже попробовал написать( не работает):

```
public List<GameObject> players;
GameObject s;
public int l = -1;
GameObject rand;
GameObject hug;
GameObject gh1;
GameObject gh2;
GameObject gh3;
GameObject gh4;
GameObject gh5;
GameObject gh6;
GameObject gh7;
GameObject gh8;
GameObject gh9;
GameObject gh10;

void Awake()
{
    gh1 = Resources.Load("amongus") as GameObject;
    gh2 = Resources.Load("amongus 1") as GameObject;
    gh3 = Resources.Load("amongus 2") as GameObject;
    gh4 = Resources.Load("amongus 3") as GameObject;
    gh5 = Resources.Load("amongus 4") as GameObject;
    gh6 = Resources.Load("amongus 5") as GameObject;
    gh7 = Resources.Load("amongus 6") as GameObject;
    gh8 = Resources.Load("amongus 7") as GameObject;
    gh9 = Resources.Load("amongus 8") as GameObject;
    gh10 = Resources.Load("amongus 9") as GameObject;

}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am") == 1)
    {
        players.Remove(gh1);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am1") == 2)
    {
        players.Remove(gh2);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am2") == 3)
    {
        players.Remove(gh3);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am3") == 4)
    {
        players.Remove(gh4);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am4") == 5)
    {
        players.Remove(gh5);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am5") == 6)
    {
        players.Remove(gh6);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am6") == 7)
    {
        players.Remove(gh7);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am7") == 8)
    {
        players.Remove(gh8);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am8") == 9)
    {
        players.Remove(gh9);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("am9") == 10)
    {
        players.Remove(gh10);
    }
    rand = players[Random.Range(0, players.Count)];
    foreach (GameObject k in players)
    {
        l += 1;
        hug = players[l];
        
        if (hug == rand)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(rand.name, new Vector3(Random.Range(0, players.Count), -1.142f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            players.RemoveAt(l);
            if(hug.gameObject.name == "amongus")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am", 1);
            else if(hug.gameObject.name == "amongus 1")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am1", 2);
            else if (hug.name == "amongus 2")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am2", 3);
            else if (hug.name == "amongus 3")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am3", 4);
            else if (hug.name == "amongus 4")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am4", 5);
            else if (hug.name == "amongus 5")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am5", 6);
            else if (hug.name == "amongus 6")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am6", 7);
            else if (hug.name == "amongus 7")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am7", 8);
            else if (hug.name == "amongus 8")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am8", 9);
            else if (hug.name == "amongus 9")
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("am9", 10);
            l = -1;
            return;
        }
    }

   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

public void Leave()
{
    PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
}
public override void OnLeftRoom()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

Это скрипт GameManager, который спавнит игроков(с моим тупым кодом). Онлайн делаю через photon.

Comment: А что, вместо gh1, gh2, gh3... массивом никак нельзя обойтись?

Comment: У игроков в photon есть actorId. Можно назначать скин в зависимости от него. Если игра не начинается пока не соберутся все, можно использовать скрипт playerNumber из примеров. В конце концов выбор скина можно зарепить за мастер клиентом.